# How can I get to the derivative of polynomial using LinkedList?

Tags: c++

Below is my  code that writes the function which is to get derivative of polynomial using `LinkedList`. The parameter of the function is `polynomial`. The code that works correctly for expressions with x  but ıt works incorrectly for values that do not contain x. How can I get derivative for values that do not contain x ?

For example, if the polynomial is -x^3-6x^2+ 4x+22, the output is -3.0x^2 -12.0x +4.0+0.0x^-1.

I'm trying to delete constant term. How can I do this ?

```
struct PolyNode {
    double coef;             
    int exp;                 
    struct PolyNode* next;   
};
PolyNode *Derivative(PolyNode *poly)
{
        PolyNode* node = new PolyNode;
        node = poly;

        while (node != NULL)
        {
            node->coef = node->coef * node->exp;
            node->exp = node->exp - 1;
            node= node->next;
        }
        return poly;
}
```

Comment: Please provide few input and corresponding output.

Comment: Note that `PolyNode* node = new PolyNode;` followed immediately by `node = poly;` is a memory leak.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this function is expected to return a new polynomial, not modify an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be discarding nodes whose exponent was originally 0, since the derivative of a constant function is 0.

Since you're not doing that, you'll probably get every polynomial that's not divisible by x - wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the following

1. polynomial is of form an*x^n + ... +a2*x^2 + a1*x^1 + a0
2. exponents can only be integers
3. there is only one term with one exponent else you will need to add those up before or during the process
4. the unknown is x by default

Then the answer is very simple check for the case where exp is zero
and handle it seperately

```
while (node != NULL) {
  if(node->exp == 0) {
    node->coef = 0;
    node->exp = 0;
    node= node->next;
  }
  else {
    node->coef = node->coef * node->exp;
    node->exp = node->exp - 1;
    node= node->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked, but it prints as 0 instead of deleting the constant. how can I fix this ?